# Is there a way i can use groupby.sum and keep other columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, data-analysis

Lets say I got a text file ~40 columns, and
I need to drop duplicates / group by using 5 column's i.e.

```
0    1    2    3    4      5     6
a    b    c    d    123    5     h
r    b    c    d    123    15    0
a    b    c    d    456    12    v
g    h    c    t    456    4     h
```

I want `groupby` or `df.drop_duplicates()`

```
df = df.groupby([1,2,4])[5].sum().reset_index()
```

so the result would be like

```
1   2   4     5
b   c   123   20
b   c   456   12
h   c   456   4
```

Is there a way, that I get other columns into this result data, because they're not wanted as `groupby` condition?

Comment: what is your expected output?,
the code you provided does what you want, so I would use: `df.groupby([1,2,4],as_index=False)[5].sum()`

Comment: the result i want is that i keep all 7 columns
edit: with extra columns as index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can partition by columns while keeping the other columns using transform:

```
df['sum'] = df.groupby([1,2,4])[5].transform(sum)
```

This will simply add a column that has the aggregation at the grouped level for all rows in the original dataframe.

Comment: i figure some not as smotth solution to this, but i added to your comment :

`data['sum'] = data.groupby([3,5])[10].transform(sum)`
`data = data.drop_duplicates([3,5])`
`data[10] = data['sum']`
`data = data.drop(columns = ['sum'])`